# Populating drop downs with MySQL entries

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a MySQL database that contains, amongst other things, 2 tables. One is the `events` table, containing event names and other details. The other is the `instance` table. This table links the `events` table to a `venue` table and adds a date, so each row is an instance of the linked event.

I am making an event booking form for internal use for these events. I want to allow selection of the event to be booked via a dropdown list. So, I have populated one dropdown with the event names:

```
$qEvent = "SELECT event_name, event_id FROM events";
$rEvent = mysqli_query($dbc,$qEvent);

echo '<select>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rEvent)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['event_id'].'">'.$row['event_name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

What I now want to do is, for the selected event, grab all the instances associated with that event, and populate another dropdown with the dates.

Can I do this with PHP, or do I need to dip into Javascript? I think I just need some way to grab the event_id value of the dropdown selection and then query based on that, but I don't know how without Javascript.

Comment: You need to dip into Javascript if you want the SELECT menu to be populated live without reloading the page.

Comment: Are you using jQuery anywhere else?

Comment: Not on this part of the site, but there's nothing stopping me using it really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking at Javascript or jQuery for achieving your goal. I've used jQuery based on my question to you earlier. It's also simpler and less code.

**Your PHP:**

Add an ID attribute `event_menu` to your select menu

```
echo '<select id="event_menu">';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rEvent)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['event_id'].'">'.$row['event_name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

<div id="container_for_new_menu"></div>
```

**Using jQuery:**

```
$('#event_menu').on('change', function() {
    // get selected value and build data string for AJAX
    var event_selected = "event_selected="+$(this).val();

    // send the selected data to a PHP page to build the populated menu
    $.ajax({
        url : 'populate-menu.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data : event_selected,
        dataType : 'html',
        success : function(data) {
            $('#container_for_new_menu').html(data);
        }, error : function() {
            alert("Something went wrong!");
        }
    });
});
```

On **populate-menu.php**, have something like:

```
$event_selected = isset($_POST['event_selected']) ? $_POST['event_selected'] : null;

// do SQL query here based on user's selection
// making sure you validate the data in the POST request for malicious BS
// or use parameterized queries

// then build a new menu to send back
echo '<select>';
    // loop through results and build options
echo '</select>';
```

This new menu will then be posted back to your original page into the `container_for_new_menu` element.

Comment: Worked perfectly first time, thanks very much. In some cases I have events at different venues but on the same date, I assume I could just do the same thing on the second dropdown to grab those?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you want to populate the "instances" dropdown based on the selection the user makes on the "event" dropdown. You cannot do this without Javascript.

My suggested way of doing this is to use AJAX to pull the instance data and populate the "instances" dropdown on change of the "event" dropdown. Useful resources below for simple AJAX get with jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/

Comment: Why do it with ajax? Why not just populate all the data on the page in JSON and then populate the SELECT with that? Much faster.

Comment: @Styphon but also not very scalable. If the instance data grows into the thousands, you will be outputting huge quantities of information. This is what AJAX was designed for.

Comment: @Styphon, so grabbing 10,000,000 rows of data is faster? Nah.

Comment: Who mentioned 10,000,000 rows? He stated an internal booking form, not some large scale commercial application. Anyone building something for that much data wouldn't be asking such a simple question. Your point is moot.

Comment: @Styphon people come here to learn. Your perception of their ability or experience is not justification to teach bad practice.

Comment: @Styphon, who said he **didn't** have 10m rows? Always provide answers or suggestions that can scale up if needed. My point is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of Javascript to accomplish this. Either:
Basic- submit the form on select and let php populate the instance drop-down. 
More elegant- use Javascript to make an Ajax call on select which will dynamically replace the instance drop-down's div.

Answer (score -2):

You will need JavaScript to populate the second drop down box. I suggest you load all the values into JSON on the page and then you can just use a jQuery on change event to populate the second select box.