# PHP/JSON encoding

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I am populating a dropdown with MySQL entries using the technique in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20640820/1703330). This works fine - when I select an event, a new dropdown is generated containing the dates that event is running on.

However, I also need to retrieve the cost of the event from the database, and assign it as the value of a form input. The simplest way to do it would be to assign it to the value attribute of the event dropdown, but this is already used to generate the second dropdown.

So, I figure I can use another Ajax call in the `change` event of the event dropdown to query the database again and get the cost, then pass it back as a JSON encoded variable. Here are my Ajax calls:

```
$('#event_menu').on('change', function() {
    // get selected value and build data string for AJAX
    var event_selected = "event_selected="+$(this).val();

    // send the selected data to a PHP page to build the populated menu
    $.ajax({
        url : 'populate_menu.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data : event_selected,
        dataType : 'html',
        success : function(data) {
        $('#instancemenu').html(data);
        }, error : function() {
            alert("Something went wrong!");
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url : 'get_eventprice.php',
        type: 'POST',
        date: event_selected,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data){
            $('#totalcost').val(data);
        }, error : function(){
            alert("Something went wrong with the price setter!")
        }
    });
});
```

And here's the code in `get_eventprice.php`:

```
    $event_selected = isset($_POST['event_selected']) ? $_POST['event_selected'] : null;

    $q="SELECT event_cost FROM events WHERE event_id=$event_selected";
    $r=mysqli_query($dbc,$q);

    $row=mysqli_fetch_field($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($row['course_cost']);
```

However, this triggers the error clause in the Ajax call. I've also tried `mysqli_fetch_array`, but with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable towards SQL injection, and will be a problem in the future - either on purpose or by accident. **Never trust user variables.** Check out [bobby-tables.com](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Avoid** using string interpolation to accomplish this.

Comment: Btw, if course_cost is just a numeric value, you can skip `json_encode` around it.

Comment: @nl-x tried that, still doesn't work

Comment: @h2ooooooo how does using prepared statements compare to filtering the POSTed variables with `mysqli_real_escape_string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second Ajax you write `date` in stead of `data`

**edit:**

Furthermore, use Element Inspector of your browser, and look in:

- the Net tab what is going on during the Ajax call. See if the data is indeed being sent along. And what the web server returns.
- the Console tab to see if you are getting any javascript messages/errors

Comment: Good eye. This is indeed the problem. But perhaps ElendilTheTall also needs some validation server-side to address this type of error.

Comment: Yes you do... look in your own code you posted. `datE: event_selected,`

Comment: @ElendilTheTall : yes you do

Comment: and now please fix your sql injection problem , as h2ooooo stated :)

Comment: Got it - `mysqli_fetch_field` expects 1 parameter. I removed `MYSQLI_ASSOC` and it works. Thanks!